# Questions marked as unclear

Tags: discussion

I have noticed before that some of the moderators had marked my question as "Unclear" and it told me to edit the question to make it more clear. I edited my question to make sure, it was as clear as possible after.(I, myself, realized it was unclear before). However, even after I edited it, the count of the moderators who marked it as unclear remained the same. Do moderators have the privilege of going back and unmarking the question as unclear. Do moderators really go back and see if the user tried his best to make it clear?

Comment: Upvoted because curious.

Comment: No, we don't always, or at least, we don't immediately. You didn't even give people a full **day** to look at your question again before you went and [deleted it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816230/post-redirect-get-function-good-or-bad).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess because 4 moderators already marked it as unclear and I edited the question many times but it was still marked unclear by all the mods so I figured maybe it was best for me to solve on my own and delete the question.

Comment: If you're referring to this (now deleted) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816230/post-redirect-get-function-good-or-bad , your edits placed it into the reopen review queue. However, three reviewers thought that your edits did not do enough to justify reopening: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4882648

Comment: I actually wasn't too worried about that one particular question, I just wanted to give an example. I was curious ever since though about the whole situation about "Unclear question" and how they are dealt with. Thank you for explaining your thought on it though.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you mentioned 4 moderators, I assume you actually just mean "people with vote to close privileges." If they were actually mods, one vote would've been enough to close the question.

---

(Speaking from the perspective of someone with vote-to-close privileges)

We do have the ability to go back to a question, see if it has improved, and revoke a close vote if it's been improved enough, but we don't actually exercise that ability often. At least for me, the main reasons are 1) because nowadays there are too many bad questions to make keeping track of them all practical and 2) because more often than not, the asker ragequits instead of taking advice and improving.

For actually reversing downvotes or votes to close, there's not a whole lot you can do if you don't know who cast the votes. Deleting the question actually complicates things, since a lot of us (anyone with 3000-9999 rep, myself included) can cast a close vote, but can't see deleted posts.

As far as what you've done already, it's good that you went back and improved the question; that's *exactly* what you're supposed to do, and the most practical thing you *can* do. As far as deleting the question goes, I see no problems with deleting the question, editing it until it's improved and ready for action, then undeleting. Deleting and leaving a question alone should really only happen if it's beyond salvaging; poorly received questions that are deleted still factor in deciding question bans.

Comment: A couple other thoughts: if we revoke a close vote we can't revote to close (another reason to be careful), and if your question does get incorrectly closed, you can try to get it reopened. (If it's vastly improved and on-topic, it'll almost certainly get reopened)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I actually wasn't too worried about that one particular question, I just wanted to give an example. I was curious ever since though about the whole situation about "Unclear question" and how they are dealt with.